# WPF Tableview swallows focus

Tags: wpf, focus, tableview

I have a DXGrid that contains a TableView.

My Issue is that once I tab into the table view (SNOOP is showing it it focused), I never can exit out of the table view control.

There are other controls after the tableview.

All tabindexs are correctly set.

Thanks